# Can't import SQL file to server

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I was trying to import a dump file via phpMyAdmin panel, but it failed.

**phpMyAdmin SQL Dump:**

```
version 3.4.5
http://www.phpmyadmin.net

Host: localhost
Generation Time: May 14, 2013 at 08:30 AM
Server version: 5.5.24
PHP Version: 5.4.3
```

Using the command:

```
SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
```

I got the following error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'phpMyAdmin SQL Dump version 3.4.5 http://www.phpmyadmin.net Host: lo' at line 1

Changing `localhost` to `www.sitename.com` doesn't work at all.

Could you, please, help me to resolve this problem.

Comment: are you running the same version of mysql on generating and importing servers?

Comment: I think I am but I can be mistaken

Comment: Your sql file has a line like `phpMyAdmin SQL Dump -- version 3.4.5` ? Remove that as that is not valid sql. (or comment it out)

Comment: It didn't work and after importing the file I got more errors

Comment: Good point JNevill - that line should start with '-- ' as well to be a comment.  And Hot, there should be a line that starts with '--  Server version' which gives you the mysql version.  You can compare that with the one you're trying to import to.  Also, if the beginning of your file was corrupted (missing a couple characters evidently) some other part might be?  Can you retrieve a backup?

Comment: George M, the file isn't corrupted, I imported this file to other site's sql server without any problem. I tried to upload the oroginal one and every time I have the same issue

Comment: Guys, thanks for help! I deleted the previous version of database and made a new one based on the previous and that worked, the import was successful.